# How do I delete all files since DATE in Slack?

Tags: bash, slack, slack-api

I would like to know how I could delete all files since 30 days using Slack API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't found Stackoverflow answers to that question, I've created a one line bash script to do it :

```sh
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxp-yourtoken' \
https://slack.com/api/files.list\?ts_to\=$(date -d "$date -30 days" +"%s") \
| jq -r '.files[] | .id' \
| xargs -I {} -n 1 curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxp-yourtoken' \
https://slack.com/api/files.delete\?file\={}
```

What this command will do :

1. It'll get the list of all files since 30 days from slack api;
2. It parse the JSON answer and return the id of the files in a newline separated list.
3. Then for every ID, it'll call files.delete.

You will need :

1. jq to parse the json : `sudo apt install jq`
2. A slack authorized app to get your Bearer key

You need to create a new slack-api app, then choose Permissions as features and functionality just as bellow :

[image]

And finally, you go in OAuth & Permissions and copy the key.

Enjoy!

Comment: Note that this will not delete ALL files though. Only the files which are visible to the user who authed your app, e.g. you would not see files uploaded to some private channels or direct messages. To delete all files you need tokens from all users of your workspace. See also this answer on the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833228/how-to-find-and-possibly-delete-personal-files/40109934#40109934

Comment: I get `{"ok":false,"error":"cant_delete_file"}` for all files. I installed the app as the owner of the workspace. I enabled all the oauth permissions, but even that didn't fix it. Is there some new step that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer but a big comment)

I'm not a huge fan of gigantic one-liners. How about this for something easier to maintain:

```
list_files() {
    local last_month=$(date -d "30 days ago" "+%s")
    local url="https://slack.com/api/files.list?ts_to=$last_month"
    local curl_opts=( 
        -X GET 
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" 
    )
    curl "${curl_opts[@]}" "$url"
}

extract_ids() {
    jq -r '.files[] | .id'
}

delete_files() {
    local url="https://slack.com/api/files.delete?file={}"
    local curl_opts=( 
        -X POST 
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" 
    )
    xargs -I {} -n 1 curl "${curl_opts[@]}" "$url"
}

token='xoxp-yourtoken'
list_files | extract_ids | delete_files
```

Comment: That is really clean. I like it!